# Remove readmore titles from joomla

Tags: joomla

How can I remove the article title from the readmore link in Joomla?
I don't have sh404SEF.

```
<?php if ($this->item->readmore_register) :
        echo JText::_('Register to read more...');
    elseif ($readmore = $this->item->params->get('readmore')) :
        echo $readmore;
    else :
        echo JText::sprintf('Read more', $this->escape($this->item->title));

    endif; ?>
```

Change this rule:

```
echo JText::sprintf('Read more', $this->escape($this->item->title));
```

To:

```
echo 'Read More';
```

Is also not corrent  because it's not multilangual.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but that's now working for me, I found this solution:

change

```
echo JText::sprintf('Read more', $this->escape($this->item->title));
```

to

```
echo JText::_('READ MORE');
```

And you can change the text in language/nl-NL.com_content.ini and the other languages too
just search for read more

Answer (score 0):

In short, change

```
echo JText::sprintf('Read more', $this->escape($this->item->title));
```

to

```
echo JText::sprintf('Read more...');
```

Note: that is not Joomla 1.5 default behaviours, so i guess you're getting that behaviour from the specific template you are using. You can confirm this by going to the Template Manager in backend and changing your default template to "rhuk_milkyway".
To change template output, you can look into folder /templates/[your template]/html/com_content/category (or .../frontpage, or .../section) for the file to edit.